# Am i doing it in right wat? predict stock price

Tags: java, neural-network, encog

I prepared csv file with the input data for neural network, and csv file where i can test my neural network. The results are not satisfactory. I was trying increase/decrease size of input data. Probably i missing something and i would be glad if someone can some tips etc. Here is my encog code:

```
    //input data
    File file = new File("path to file");
    CSVFormat format = new CSVFormat('.', ',');
    VersatileDataSource source = new CSVDataSource(file, false, format);
    VersatileMLDataSet data = new VersatileMLDataSet(source);
    data.getNormHelper().setFormat(format);

    ColumnDefinition wig20OpenN = data.defineSourceColumn("wig20OpenN", 0, ColumnType.continuous);
    (...)

    ColumnDefinition futureClose = data.defineSourceColumn("futureClose", 81, ColumnType.continuous);

    data.analyze();
    data.defineSingleOutputOthersInput(futureClose);
    EncogModel model = new EncogModel(data);

    //TYPE_RBFNETWORK, TYPE_SVM, TYPE_NEAT, TYPE_FEEDFORWARD <- this type of method i was trying
    model.selectMethod(data, MLMethodFactory.TYPE_SVM);
    model.setReport(new ConsoleStatusReportable());

    data.normalize();

    model.holdBackValidation(0.001, true, 10);
    model.selectTrainingType(data);
    MLRegression bestMethod = (MLRegression)model.crossvalidate(20, true);
    // Display the training and validation errors.
    System.out.println( "Training error: " + model.calculateError(bestMethod, model.getTrainingDataset()));
    System.out.println( "Validation error: " + model.calculateError(bestMethod, model.getValidationDataset()));
    NormalizationHelper helper = data.getNormHelper();

    File testingData = new File("path to testing file");
    ReadCSV csv = new ReadCSV(testingData, false, format);
    String[] line = new String[81];
    MLData input = helper.allocateInputVector();
    while(csv.next()) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            for(int i = 0; i <81; i++){
            line[i] = csv.get(i);
        }

            String correct = csv.get(81);
            helper.normalizeInputVector(line,input.getData(),false);
            MLData output = bestMethod.compute(input);
            String irisChosen = helper.denormalizeOutputVectorToString(output)[0];

            result.append(Arrays.toString(line));
            result.append(" -> predicted: ");
            result.append(irisChosen);
            result.append("(correct: ");
            result.append(correct);
            result.append(")");

            System.out.println(result.toString());
        }

        // Delete data file and shut down.
        filename.delete();
        Encog.getInstance().shutdown();
```

What i was trying so far is to change the `MLMethodFactory`, but had problems here, only `TYPE_RBFNETWORK`, `TYPE_SVM`, `TYPE_NEAT`, `TYPE_FEEDFORWARD` this type works fine, for example if i changed it to `TYPE_PNN` i had following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.encog.EncogError: Please call selectTraining first to choose how to train.
```

Ok i know from documentation that i should use this method:

```
selectTraining(VersatileMLDataSet dataset, String trainingType, String trainingArgs)
```

But the string type for traningtype and triningArgs is confusing.

And last question what about saving the neural after traning to file, and loading it to check on the traning data? As i would like to have this separately.

Edit: I forgot the size of the input data is 1500.

Comment: Can you please present what do you have in your text files? Also what was normalized results?

Comment: From the input or output? or both?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Uh4aNnh2 <input for training and for test. I have no idea how to save normalized results. Any suggestion?

Comment: and the results: http://pastebin.com/6LRfZy7z. for method NEAT.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you not satisfied with your results, but it is relatively fine. I propose you to consider adding scaling to your training. You have 81 columns, and in your input row I see data like 16519.1600, also 2315.94, and even -0.6388282285709328. For neural network it is hard to adjust weights correctly for such different inputs. 

P.S. scaling is also normalizing of columns!. As usually in books is described normalizing of rows, but normalizing of columns is also important.

Comment: Yes results is fine but i would like to be better as the sometimes the predicted value is much higher or lower than the correct value. Anyway i figured out how to save the normalized files and its looks fine: http://pastebin.com/0vVP5WF3 please take a look, so i have to experiment with less data or other parameters. Thanks for your time, and help!

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Cybernetic-Trading-Strategies-State-Art/dp/0471149209 in this book it is recommended to predict not future price, but future indicators values with usage of neural networks ( for example moving averages crossover ). Another advice in this book is join some trading strategy with neural networks together in order to improve precision of trading strategy.

Comment: Ok thanks for link. What do you mean about join some trading strategy? Because what i want to achieve is get the correct direction on the index, and base on that direction open two opposite position. One short on index, and second on batch of stocks in that index (which stocks will be depends on another indicators) and for example if the neural work predict the up direction, i will open 40% short on index and 60% long on the stocks in index.

Comment: I use neural networks for trading at forex. In my quantitative research as usually I go to http://www.forexfactory.com/forumdisplay.php?f=71, choose some trading strategy, which has performance for example 40% of reliability and some good R/R ratio ( at least 1:1 ). Then I train neural network with values from that strategy until I get performance around 60%. Then make forward testing and then try to trade

Comment: Ok i got your point, thank you very much! Last question do you use meta trader? And its programming language?

Comment: I've used it. But for now I switched to jForex because it allows to test tick data, and MT4 or MT5 doesn't all-new this. Also jForex allows to use different timeframes which are not available in metatrader 4